# Performance overhead for multiple instantiations of UdpClient

Tags: c#, instantiation, udpclient

I am using UDP to send data packets from one application, to another, over the Internet.

```
using( var udpClient = new UdpClient())
{
    udpClient.Send(bytes,  bytes.Length, endPoint);
}
```

This gets executed very frequently  (in the ms range) and multiple times  (about 1000 times ).

What is the performance overhead of doing this compared to creating a single  instance of `UdpClient` and disposing of it at the end of the program, when all `Send` commands have been performed?

Which is the better approach and are there any advantages/disadvantages of one approach over the other?

Comment: I would more bother about bandwith wastage when sending tons of miniscule packets. The in program overhead is a lot smaller compared to the ridiculous waste you create.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the bandwidth  wastage at the moment. I can always reduce the calls to`Send`, change packet format, reduce packet size etc. I am concerned about application performance, hence my question.

Comment: Your main overhead well be in the handshake and negotiation of an ephemeral port. The most limiting of these is that Windows will rate limit the creation of these ephemeral port bindings, especially since you are using the blocking io call of `client.Send`.

Comment: @Aron UDP does not handshake. I'm also not aware of any rate limit. Is this well known or do you have a reference?

Comment: @pookie all this does is cause some CPU overhead. You need to measure this. There is no way to derive the answer without measuring.

Comment: @usr Thanks, I will perform some testing.

Comment: @pookie let us know what you find. I'm interested and also it happens often that the benchmark code is invalid :)